# Code Blocks terminal issue

Tags: c++, c, macos, codeblocks, osx-yosemite

I have a problem with code blocks on mac. When I try to run my program the terminal does not open and nothing happens.

This is the message in the box:

```
gcc -Wall -g  -c "/Users/Andrewmezz/Documents/Progetti Università/ContaMaiuscole/main.c" -o obj/Debug/main.o

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/Andrewmezz/Documents/Progetti Universit‡/ContaMaiuscole/main.c'
clang: error: no input files
```

I have xcode intalled and command line tools. I use Net Beans and works but code blocks does not work. Please help me.

Comment: The compiler is trying to tell you that the file */Users/Andrewmezz/Documents/Progetti Università/ContaMaiuscole/main.c* does not exist. If this file actually exists, you may be having problems due to the presence of the `à` character in its filename. try restricting yourself to ASCII characters.

Comment: It's probably the space in "/Progetti Università/". If you remove the space it might work.

Comment: Actually, since there are quotes around the path it might not be the spaces.

Comment: Which was the issue?